# App creating a graph/text file on tablet and sending it to PC

Tags: java, android, swing, jfreechart

Im quite new to programming in java and am trying to write my first app on android.

I want to make an app which will take some data input, create a graph/text file and send it to my PC (via Mail/Dropbox). I have most of the code regarding what to do with the data set up and am now thinking about how to create the file on the tablet and how to send it over to the PC.

I was thinking to use Excel or sth like JFreeChart(does this work on Android?) to create the file and Mail or Dropbox to send it.

Are there better ways to do it? (Or are my ideas bad?)
Im open to any suggestions regarding the question.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Another idea is to create a "RunMe" file on the Tablet, sending it to the PC, which will then draw the graph and create the text file there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google's api for this. You can create any thing either it is doc or excel sheet . And you can also mail it using the same api. Go have a look on Google doc api and it's uses. I hope it will work.